# Elasticsearch wildcard VS querystring

Tags: elasticsearch, sql-like

I've found 2 approaches for *Like-Search* in Elasticsearch. Which one of those whould I choose? They seem to have the same behaviour. Or is there even a better one?

**query_string:**

```
"query": {
"bool": {
  "filter": [
    {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "*quick*",
        "fields": [
          "text"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
}
```

**wildcard:**

```
"query": {
"bool": {
    "must": [
        {
            "wildcard": {
                "text": "*quick*"
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

SQL would be `WHERE text like '%quick%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the difference is, that in the filter query no scores are calculated. In the documentation:
*In filter context, a query clause answers the question “Does this document match this query clause?” The answer is a simple Yes or No — no scores are calculated.*

So i would use wildcard query. There you can use * for more characters and ? for only one character - depending on your needs. And here, the scores are calculated.

Comment: So if I don't need scores and want to keep the the load of my elasticsearch-server low the _filter_ is the better choice?

Comment: Yes. I understand this from the documentation.

Comment: tank you for your response